# How can i fix this SliverPersistentHeader Renderflexerror?

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

[Gif of said error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGvPZ.gif) 
I have a SliverPersistentHeader, that as a sliver does what it is supposed to do. However the content in the sliver causes renderflex errors. 
How do i fix it, so that the content inside the sliver resizes with the sliver? I choose the SliverPersistentHeader to create a stack of headers, maybe there is another widget that would be more fitting?

The slivers are built in a CustomScrollView as objects in a list of slivers.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:weather/weather.dart';[enter image description here][1]
import 'dart:math' as math;


class TracksPage extends StatelessWidget{
  TracksPage();

  List tracks = List();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){   


    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

      ),
      body: CollapsingList()


    );

  }}

 class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  _SliverAppBarDelegate({
    @required this.minHeight,
    @required this.maxHeight,
    @required this.child,
  });
  final double minHeight;
  final double maxHeight;
  final Widget child;
  @override
  double get minExtent => minHeight;
  @override
  double get maxExtent => math.max(maxHeight, minHeight);
  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, 
      double shrinkOffset, 
      bool overlapsContent) 
  {
    return new SizedBox.expand(child: child);
  }
  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return maxHeight != oldDelegate.maxHeight ||
        minHeight != oldDelegate.minHeight ||
        child != oldDelegate.child;
  }
}

class CollapsingList extends StatelessWidget {
  SliverPersistentHeader makeHeader(List<int> sums, int tracks, DateTime day) {
    return SliverPersistentHeader(
      pinned: true,
      delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
        minHeight: 0.0,
        maxHeight: 80.0,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[400]),
            color: Colors.white
          ),
          child: ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            child: Text(tracks.toString(), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),),
            title: Text(" ${day.day}/${day.month}/${day.year}"),
           subtitle: Row(children: <Widget>[
              statCircle(Image.asset("assets/images/steps.png", height: 20, fit: BoxFit.cover,), [Color(0xFFC312E4), Color(0xFF841779)], sums[0].toString(), 0),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),),
              statCircle(Icon(Icons.timer, size: 15,), [Color(0xFF73E412), Color(0xFF5B9B1A)], "", 5),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),),
              statCircle(Icon(Icons.pin_drop, size: 15,), [Color(0xFF12D6E4), Color(0xFF118470)], sums[1].toString(), 5),]),
          )
        )
      ),
    );
  }
  Column statCircle(Widget child, List<Color> colors, String info, double padding){
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        child: child,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(  
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: colors,
            stops: [0.3, 0.6],
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter
            )
           ),
        ),
        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: padding),),
     Text(info)
     ],);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection("collectionName").where("fieldName", isEqualTo:fieldVariable).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          List dates = extractAndSort(snapshot);
           return  CustomScrollView(
             slivers:  makeSlivers(dates, context)
           );
        }
        else return Container();
      }
    );

  }

  makeSlivers(List dates, BuildContext context){
    List<Widget> slivers = new List<Widget>();
    List totals = summarize(Globals.tracks);
    int length;
    if(Globals.tracks != null){
      length = Globals.tracks.length;
    } else length = 0;

    slivers.add( makeCirclesHeader(totals[0], length, totals[1], context));
    slivers.add(SliverPadding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 20,
                    color: Colors.white)
                )
              ));
    if(dates != null)
    {dates.forEach((date) {
      List tracks = Globals.tracks.where((track) => track.trackCreated.toDate().day == date.day).toList();
      slivers.add(makeHeader(summarize(tracks), tracks.length, date));
      slivers.add(sliverListDay(tracks));
    });}
    return slivers;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap it like this: _SliverAppBarDelegate -> Container -> ClipRect -> OverflowBox -> ListTile

[image: 1]

```dart
      delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
        minHeight: 0.0,
        maxHeight: 80.0,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[400]),
            color: Colors.white
          ),
          child: ClipRect(
            child: OverflowBox(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              maxHeight: 80.0,
              child: ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  ...
```

Comment: Thank you will try it later ☺️